# Il verbo 'pensare' senza l'uso del congiuntivo

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood

Ho trovato in un libro la frase seguente:

> Doveva avere dieci o undici anni, pensò, quando sua madre era
>   scomparsa.

Perché non si usa il congiuntivo?

> Dovesse avere dieci o undici anni, pensò, quando sua madre era
>   scomparsa.

Qualcuno mi può spiegare come mai non si usa il congiuntivo in questa frase?
Si usa il congiuntivo soltanto se si usa la congiunzione 'penso che'?
È perchè si tratta di un discorso indiretto? Oppure perchè 'dovere + verbo' indica già una cosa incerta?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su ItalianSE!!

Comment: Si sta riportando un discorso diretto (che avviene nel pensiero, ma è grammaticalmente lo stesso che un discorso orale).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

“Doveva avere dieci o undici anni quando sua madre era scomparsa” è un discorso diretto. Il verbo “pensò” è in un inciso per non appesantire la frase; si tratta di una tecnica molto frequente nella narrativa. Il fatto che avvenga solo nella mente di qualcuno non ha rilevanza grammaticale.

> “Siamo a buon porto”, pensò fra sé don Abbondio; e, con un fare più manieroso che mai, – via, – disse: – in quindici giorni cercherò,… procurerò…

In un discorso indiretto il congiuntivo ci vuole: “pensò che dovesse avere dieci o undici anni”.

Answer (score 0):

Non sono d'accordo che l'uso del verbo pensare si porti necessariamente dietro l'uso del congiuntivo. La forma col congiuntivo assegna semplicemente alla frase un tono più "alto".

La domanda ha senso, però, dal momento che la strategia usata nelle scuole italiane per spiegare il congiuntivo fa acqua da tutte le parti e confonde gli studenti. Io parlerei senza mezzi termini di "fantagrammatica". Se la grammatica deve spiegare come funziona la lingua, la storiella del congiuntivo come "modo dell'ipotesi, del dubbio e del bla, bla, bla" semplicemente non regge. È facilissimo costruire frasi dove il congiuntivo non ci starebbe (in accordo a quella regola), ma gli italiani avvertono che, a orecchio, ci sta (pur non sapendolo spiegare ovviamente).

L'uso del congiuntivo italiano è un retaggio del latino ed è legato prevalentemente alla possibilità di conferire ai propri scritti un tono più elevato qualora il registro lo richieda.

Ho scritto un articolo in proposito che dovrebbe dissipare la maggior parte dei dubbi: https://www.lavocedinewyork.com/arts/lingua-italiana/2019/10/25/il-congiuntivo-italiano-cari-studenti-stranieri-attenti-alla-fantagrammatica/